# OpenDNS servers initial response is very slow

Tags: windows, dns, dhcp, opendns

I've got a Time Warner cable ISP package (RoadRunner), and the modem they gave me doesn't allow me to specify which DNS servers to use; it always uses whatever the upstream dhcp server gives it.  I prefer to use OpenDNS on my home network, so i've configured a couple of my PCs manually in the Windows adapter settings for IPv4 such that their IP addresses are obtained via DHCP, but the DNS server settings are fixed to the OpenDNS server IPs.

Now, when I startup Windows on these PCs, it always takes 2-3 minutes to start receiving responses from the DNS servers; any request before that times out.  While not debilitating, this is quite annoying.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: out of curiosity are you using a wireless modem+router combo or do you have one PC connected to the modem and then using ICS to share that connection with the rest of the computers?

Comment: Do other DNS servers get delayed in the same way? try this to see if you can get better performance from other DNS servers http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

Comment: @Xantec it's a modem/router device.

Comment: @jb48394 the Time Warner DNS servers don't have the same kind of delay.  I haven't tested with any others, but I'll check out the link you posted.  Thanks.

Comment: @jb48394: the OpenDNS servers showed very good response times in the test - which was expected. It's during the first 3 minutes or so after bootup that requests always timeout.